# Right User Permissions to use ListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions method

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, csom

I'm currently using a SharePoint account as a Service account to get files and share them in an application I'm working on using **CSOM**. I filter the files according to the logged-in user to check if the user has no access to the file, then I hide it, to prevent him from trying to access it and get "Permission Denied" error.

So, I used `ListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions` for this issue, but I need to grant the user only the permissions he needs to access and make that check.

I checked the official documentation of `ListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536458(v=office.15)) but unfortunately, I found no direct clue which permission does the job.

So to recap what this service account needs to do is :

1- Execute Search across all sharepoint files [SearchExecutor].

2- Get Login Name by Email using `Utility.ResolvePrincipal` (to be used in `GetUserEffectivePermissions` function).

3- Use `GetUserEffectivePermissions` to check if the logged-in User has permission to view the file.

I'd really appreciate your help as I'm kind of new to SharePoint and I searched a lot but found no clue about what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try application permissions?

[Accessing SharePoint using an application context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly)
[Connecting to SharePoint Online programmatically: Secret vs Certificate](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-programmatically-secret-vs-certificate/)
[Access SPO Site Programmatically via MS Graph API and SharePoint API](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/access-spo-site-programmatically/)